# JMS MQ Implement retry logic without throwing exception

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I have a JMSReceiver class which is listening on a MQ Queue. This class implements the MessageListener interface. I wish to implement the logic to retry a message for specified number of times by getting the message to rollback. To do so I have to catch the business exception and wrap it in a RuntimeException so that message gets rolled back to the MQ and gets replayed. i wish to implement this in better way.

**Current Implementation**

```
class JMSReceiver implements MessageListener{
public void onMessage(Message msg){
        logger.info("**********Message received in consumer");
         try {
             //Do some business which throws a business exception
         } catch (Exception e) {
            try {
                logger.info("####Redelivery count"+msg.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount"));
                if(msg.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount")<10){
                    logger.info("####MQ ISSUE: Redelivery attempted for message. Redelivery attempt: "+msg.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount"));
                    throw new RuntimeException("Redelivery Attempted"+e.getMessage());                      
                }else{
                    logger.info("####MQ ISSUE: Redelivery attempts exhausted for message");
                }
            } catch (JMSException e1) {                 
                e1.printStackTrace();
                logger.info("####MQ ISSUE: Exception occured while getting JMSXDeliveryCount");
             }
      }
     }
```

**Expected**
The above implementation works. It rollsback the message to MQ and the redelivery count increases. I even tried doing session.rollback() but when I do that the redelivery count does not increase and I can replay the message. Please advise a better way to implement this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create JMS session with CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE as message acknowledge mode. And then in the onMessage() method, do not call msg.Acknowledge(). Not calling msg.Acknowledge() will ensure the same is delivered again.

```
session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

Note that calling Acknowledge() on one message will acknowledge all messages received since the last time the method was called.

**Update**

Session creation

```
    connection = cf.createConnection("user","password");
    System.out.println("Connection created.");
    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    System.out.println("Session created.");
```

OnMessage() method - Message is being acknowledged on 6th attempt.

```
    consumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
      public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        try {
            // Display the message that just arrived
            System.out.println(msg);

            if(msg.getIntProperty("JMSXDeliveryCount") > 5){
                msg.acknowledge();
            }
        } // end try
        catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Exception caught in onMessage():\n" + e);
        }
        return;
      } // end onMessage()
    }); // end setMessageListener
```

Comment: I have that code and the code throwing the exception is before the acknowledge. So in case of exception the message.acknowledge is never called. Still the message did not roll back. I had to put this runtime exception to get the message to rollback

Comment: I think you will need to check your session creation code. I have updated snippet I use. Messages are being redelivered to my application

Comment: Hi Shashi, i checked my code and we are using multithreading so if some other thread acknowledges the message all messages befor ethe message get acknowledge. What could be the ill effects of throwing the runtimeexception to get the message to rollback?

Comment: Also is there any option to just acknowledge the current message?

Comment: It appears that you are sharing JMS session across multiple threads. JMS spec says session should not be shared. IBM MQ JMS implementation acknowledges current and all messages received earlier.